# Kubuntu guest on Windows 8.1 Hyper-V won't shut down completely

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, windows-8.1, hyper-v, kubuntu

I've got a Windows 8.1 Professional laptop with Hyper-V installed, and a Kubuntu 14.04 Desktop VM. When I shutdown the Kubuntu VM, most of the time it gets to the logo screen, and just sits there. It's not frozen, because I can see the glow around the logo brighten and fade. I have installed the four Hyper-V modules, and lsmod shows them all running fine before the shutdown.

Also, once it's stuck on the logo screen, if I send a CTL-ALT-DEL to the VM, it restarts immediately.

Does anyone have any idea where I'd begin troubleshooting this?

UPDATE:

I've disabled the startup and shutdown screens, and now can see this output when it's stopped.  Hopefully this sheds more light on the problem.

[image: Screenshot of shutdown messages]

Comment: Maybe they changed something at the Shutdown Screen/Command. There are a lot of question like yours on kubuntu and ubuntu. I'll try it to see if i get the same Result. Which Version of the Install Disk did you use 32 or 64bit?

Comment: 32/64bit both works OK for me so how do you Shutdown via Gui or Commandline? There are 2 Possibilities 1. Its a Hyper-V based Problem. Can't help you on that, sorry i don't have Windows so no Hyper-V, but you could try out Virtualbox or VMWare Player and see if its the same there. 2. Its a Problem caused by a improper Shutdown followed by an automatic Restart (maybe cause the installation of Kubuntu didn't work all well or you installed the wrong Version for your PC) then the System Log of Kubuntu itselfs and maybe the Log of Hyper-V should help.

Comment: I used the Kubuntu 14.04 Desktop 64-bit ISO. I shut down the VM using the GUI. I've also now disabled the startup and shutdown splash screens so I can see what it's doing; hopefully I'll have more info soon.

Comment: Updated the question with the screenshot from shutdown without splash screen.Also, I've used the same ISO to install another physical computer, and it works fine, so I'm inclined to believe it's something to do with Hyper-V.

Comment: what we see there on the pic, is the  linux shutdown routine. i don't know exactly why but with some monitors some of the linux doesn't fully shutdown them (they shutdown the pc but the light on the monitor stays on and you can still see the last log entries of the shutdown like in your pic) if the last line is saying will now halt or is halted e.g the System did a normal shutdown. and you can just turn the vm off. by pressing ctrl-alt-del during boot time the same happens as if you would hit the power button during boot time the system is going to shutdown.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, been meaning to get back to this. Yeah, I usually use Gentoo at home, so I'm familiar with the startup and shutdown screens. But once it gets to the "Will now halt" step, it should send a (ACPI?) signal to the computer (in this case, the VM) to power off. I'm not sure if the signal isn't getting sent (problem with Kubuntu) or the VM isn't receiving/acting on it properly (problem with Hyper-V). And yeah, I can just power it off manually, but it should be happening automatically; if I don't power it off, my laptop takes longer to shutdown and startup as it hibernates the VM.